# Can I connect a Thunderbolt 1 MacBook Pro to a USB C display using an adapter?

Tags: thunderbolt, usb-c, macbook-pro-retina

Could I use some kind of adapter to connect the Thunderbolt (1?) port on a 2012 retina MacBook Pro to a USB C display/monitor and get any display output?

If that's possible, would the USB ports on the monitor also connect via the same Thunderbolt port?  (say I had a keyboard plugged into the monitor's USB A port for eg)